# Swipe right ONLY after at least one swipe left

Tags: objective-c

I am using left and right swipe for 'next image' and 'previous image'. On startup of the app I want to disable right swipe(previous) until at least one left swipe - is there any obvious way to do that?

Comment: What did you try? Did you search Google before coming here? See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have searched around yes, but find it rather difficult what exactly to search for. Have triends things such as: objective c +'disable function until' 'disable function conditional' etc

Comment: I found a solution by moving the code where the function for right swipe is defined into the action of the left swipe - so that the right swipe is not defined until the first left swipe has been done by the user

Comment: This method is not very clean, please look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple method to handle swipes from all UISwipeGestureRecognizer instances. This method will enable/disable the gesture recognizers by itself.

Considering that you have two recognizers, namely

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight;
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft;
```

And an array of images to be shown

```
NSArray *arrImages;
```

You will also need to maintain a global ivar

```
NSInteger currIndex; //To maintain the index
```

Both should have the same method as their selector, which is as follows:

```
-(void)handleSwipeFrom:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
{
    NSInteger newIndex = currIndex;

    if ([recognizer isEqual: swipeLeft])
    {
        newIndex ++;
    }
    else if ([recognizer isEqual: swipeRight])
    {
        newIndex --;
    }

    if (newIndex >= 0 && newIndex <= ([arrImages count] - 1))
        [self showImageAtIndex:newIndex];

}
```

The showImageAtIndex: method can handle the rest as follows:

```
-(void) showImageAtIndex: (NSInteger)index
{
    if (index == 0)
    {
        [swipeRight setEnabled:NO];
    }
    else
    {
        [swipeRight setEnabled:YES];
    }

    if (index == ([arrImages count] - 1))
    {
        [swipeLeft setEnabled:NO];
    }
    else
    {
        [swipeLeft setEnabled:YES];
    }

    currIndex = index;


//Show image at currIndex here

}
```

For this to work perfectly, you need to instantiate currIndex and call showImageAtIndex in viewDidLoad:

```
currIndex = 0;
[self showImageAtIndex: currIndex];
```